# How to make a new SQL table with extracted SQL table data?

Tags: sql, pandas, sqlite

I'm a beginner of SQlite , and about to make a new table with extracted table data. I learned the
way of making a new table from an existing table like this;

```
create table T2 select * from T1
```

so, I guess I could make a new table with extracted data like this;

```
import pandas as pd 
import sqlite3
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={'column1': [10, 20, 30, 40], 
          'column2': [0, 1, 1, 0],
          'column3': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b']})


dbname = 'TEST.db'
con = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
cur = con.cursor()
df.to_sql("T1",con,if_exists="replace",method="multi",chunksize=1000)
con.execute("create table if not exists T2 As (SELECT column1,column3 FROM T1 WHERE column3='a'  Group by column2)")

df_sqlquery = pd.read_sql_query(sql="SELECT * FROM T2",con=con)

print(df_sqlquery)
```

but, it didn't work and I got the error message;
"OperationalError: near "(": syntax error"
To make the new table, should I output the extracted table with pandas.read_sql and input it to SQlite with df.to_sql? I couldn't find the good answer. I'd appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: What did not work ? Do you get some kind of error ? Also can we see T1 table ?

Comment: `a='1'` ???, is `a` a column in T1?

Comment: **New Table Create Without data**
`CREATE TABLE new_table AS (SELECT * FROM old_table WHERE 1=2);`
**New Table Create With data**
`CREATE TABLE new_table AS SELECT * FROM old_table;`

Comment: @VBoka I've editted it. The content is different from my data but I got the same error message.

Comment: @Ahmed I wrote it as an example. I rewrote it.

Comment: @AmitSarker after making new table without data, should I insert the extract data into the new table? I'll try it.

Comment: So when you execute this "create table T2 select * from T1" it works and when you execute this "create table if not exists T2 As (SELECT column1,column3 FROM T1 WHERE column3='a'  Group by column2)" it does not ?

Answer (score 0):

Just change this:

```
create table if not exists T2 
As (SELECT column1,column3 FROM T1 WHERE column3='a'  Group by column2)
```

into this:

```
create table if not exists T2 
As SELECT column1,column3 FROM T1 WHERE column3='a'  Group by column2
```

That is why you get the error.

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=9a2138ed5928907097983866641ae9f0)

Comment: I made it！ I didn't know the error is responsible for the parentheses.  Thank you!

Comment: Hi @user52980 you are welcome. If the answer is correct It would be nice to accept it if you want.